# How can I make a plane's edges taper inwards?

Tags: bezier-curves, edges

How can I deform one edge or multiple edges of a plane or cube so they are tapered in and rounded equally?

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Alternatively if you want it done with actual curves

1. Add a new plane object
2. Enter edit mode
3. Subdivide it with <kbd>W</kbd> > *Subdivide* only once
4. Convert it to a curve with <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>
5. Change the curve type to *Bezier* in the tool shelf
6. Change it to *2D* type curve in the properties window
7. Select the central vertex in the middle of the sides only
8. Change their handle type to *Auto*
9. Now scale them  down towards the selection center and adjust as desired

[image]

Comment: Added image for clarity

Answer (score 11):

While in *Edit mode*, select the plane and subdivide it, by pressing <kbd>W</kbd>>*Subdivide*. You can press <kbd>F6</kbd> to adjust the number of cuts. Then, use the *Proportional Editing* tool, enabled by pressing <kbd>O</kbd>, or by going to the 3D View header, and set it's falloff to *Sphere*.

[image]

Now, select the center face/vertex and scroll the mouse so the circle doesn't contain the corner vertices and scale to taste.

[image]

Comment: it's what i want but it dose not give smooth rounded edge even when i increased the division points better results if i just subdivide olny the edge but still no smooth enough.

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative to the answers above you may do it using ***subsurf modifier*** and ***edge crease*** tool.

Add a *plane* and subdivide it once with <kbd>W</kbd>-->*Subdivide*. Scale some vertices to create the desired shape. Give it a ***subsurf modifier*** with some subdivisions. In *Edit Mode* select all the edges around the *plane* and press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>,<kbd>1</kbd> to crease them. 
[image]