# How to draw and extrude this curved figure?

Tags: bezier-curves

I'm a new Blender's user and I cannot figuring out how to do that...

Does someone can explain me how to create/draw this figure and extrude it to get a smoothed edges 3D mesh? I'd like to create a marble pedestal.

Is there any tool similar to the Adobe Illustrator Pencil tool?

[image: Curved figure]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I make a plane's edges taper inwards?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/55205/how-can-i-make-a-planes-edges-taper-inwards)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A way to do that:

Start with a plane (<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> then 'mesh' and 'plane'), enter edit mode (<kbd>Tab</kbd>), select all vertices <kbd>A</kbd> and delete <kbd>X</kbd> 'faces only'.

Still in edit mode, select the vertices, and hit <kbd>W</kbd> subdivide. Then in the operator panel, choose 2 cuts.

[image]

Now add a subsurface modifier. Set it to two subdivisions, for instance, and check 'adjust cage to modifier result' :

[image]

Select the four corners, then scale <kbd>S</kbd> :

[image]

(edit)
For the extrusion :

Select all, extrude Z <kbd>E</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd>, the add a loop cut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> and adjust it to the top.

Select the top vertices again, then scale them down a bit.

[image]

(edit, again)
If you need to close the shape :

Simply add the needed quads, and eventually add another loop cut to make the vert/horz transition more sharp:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Finally, what's the proper way to unsubdivide / simplify this mesh with less vertices?

Comment: @Jonathan, less vertices is very dependent of what you want on the final result... what are your constraints about that?

Answer (score 2):

### Final result:

[image: final]

### Creation:

1. Create a **Plane**, go to **Edit Mode**, press <kbd>W</kbd> then **Subdivide**.
2. Select vertices as shown below and delete them.

[image: 1]

3. Add **Mirror Modifier** and check **X**, **Y** and **Clipping**.
4. Add **Subdivision Surface Modifier** and set both **View** and **Render** to **2** (or higher if you need more details).
5. Select all (<kbd>A</kbd>) and subdivide it twice, as in first step - or once if you want really smooth edges.
6. Enable **Proportional Editing** and select vertices as shown below.

[image: 2]

7. Press <kbd>S</kbd> to scale and adjust **Proportional Editing** with mouse scroll then try to match shape.

[image: 3]

8. Now you can select all end **Extrude** it along **Z** axis.

### Final thoughts:

If you want harder edges you will want to add **loop cuts** (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>) as shown below:

[image: 4]

Don't forget to set shading to **Smooth**.

Answer (score 0):

### Steps

- Create a new document.
- Delete the Cube mesh.
- Align to **Top ortho** view (<kbd>NUM7</kbd>).
- Switch to **Edit mode**.
- Create a new Plane mesh.
- Delete **Only faces** (<kbd>X</kbd>).
- Subdivide it with a factor of **2** (<kbd>W</kbd>).
- Select all of the vertices (<kbd>A</kbd>).
- Add the modifier called **Subdivision Surface** to the figure.
- Check **Adjust edit cage to modifier result**.
- Choose **4** view units.
- Deselect all of the vertices (<kbd>A</kbd>).
- Select the four vertices located at each corner of the figure (<kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>Right-click</kbd>).
- Press <kbd>S</kbd> and scale them.
- Select all the vertices (<kbd>A</kbd>).
- Press <kbd>R</kbd> then <kbd>CTRL</kbd> to rotate the new figure to **45 deg**.

[image]

- Switch to **Object mode** and apply the modifier.
- Switch to **Edit mode** again.
- Select the top vertices (<kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>Right-click</kbd>).
- Add **Make Edge/Face** to create the top face of the volum.
- Add the modifier called **Bevel**.
- Adjust the **Width** and **Segments** value.
- Switch to **Object mode** and apply the modifier.

Fig. https://image.ibb.co/fW6wLa/GIF2.gif

### Final result

[image]

Comment: Can you add the steps for your solution so other people can learn?

Comment: Fixed. I'll illustrate the steps this night.