# How would you curve the edges of a 3D shape?

Tags: mesh, bezier-curves

I have a basic shape that at one end is wider than the other, the object gets thinner basically but the edges of the shape are straight, instead i want them to bow inwards.

Picture to demonstrate what i have and the red lines show what i am aiming for:

[image]

Is there some modifier for me to do this? Not sure i can see an easy way to do it manually.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I make a plane's edges taper inwards?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/55205/how-can-i-make-a-planes-edges-taper-inwards)

Comment: You can't curve edges without subdivision

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos does that work for 3D objects too ? Seems to only show how to do it for a 2D plane and that it does it to all 4 sides. Converting to a curve does nothing for it.

Comment: Add some Subdivision as Duarte Farrajota Ramos suggested and use Proportional Edting (Found just above the Timeline).

Comment: @Dontwalk but according to the answer that was linked above you only need to subdivide once. But the answers he linked to only works for a 2D plane it seems since it doesn't let me apply any curves to the 3D object when i apply scale to the central vertex.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a 3D version of your Plane.

[image]

Add some subdivisions by pressing CTRL + "R" The more subdivisions you use the smoother the curve you are after will be.

[image]

Select two edges (You could also do one at a time). Turn on Proportional Editing and choose a "Falloff" type. I choose "Smooth" here.

[image]

Press "S" to scale and the Axis you want to scale on. I pressed "S" + "Z". Use the mouse wheel to affect more or less vertices.

[image]

Add a Subsurface Modifier and "Smooth Shading" if you want a smoother look. *You can use the same method with a plane.

[image]

**EDIT** You could also do this with a "Bezier Curve". Create your shape and change the curve to 2D to fill the shape.

[image]

Comment: Oh i see, thank you :) I was selecting edges incorrectly. This was very helpful. Thanks again!