# How do I make a pillars cap, inset, with flattened edges?

Tags: mesh

So I understand how to inset a plane to make a curve from here: [How can I make a plane's edges taper inwards?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/55205/how-can-i-make-a-planes-edges-taper-inwards), but how do I flatten the edges like pic related
[image]
[image]

Comment: Hello, what kind of inner topology do you need?

Comment: So this is the top view, do you have a front view? Is what we see completely flat the extruded on Z?

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please don't post the same question more than once. If your previous question was put on hold, address raised the issues by editing it so it can be reopened rather than post a new one, otherwise see [What should I do if no one answers my question?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/no-one-answers)

Comment: Duarte please don't comment on posts like you did my previous question that is deleted and not the same as this one without reading the post first. You linked me to a post that had nothing to do with the question I asked. It was not put on hold. there was no "raised issues". The only raised issue I had with my previous post was the fact you replied with something I explained I already knew how to do. Please refer to the rules where it says read the post in its entirety before replying

Comment: feel free to go to https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/ with questions about the site

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start with a mesh plane, subdivide it and then use the knife tool to cut the corners and scale the mid-verts towards the center. Object > Convert > Curve. Go into edit mode of new curve object and select all, right-click > Set Spline Type > Bezier. Then follow the rest of the steps from the link you posted.

[image]

It won't be perfect, you'll have to adjust the curve handles a little bit.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Create a plane, bevel it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> and <kbd>V</kbd> to switch to vertices bevel:

[image]

By default it won't give what I show but you just need to tweak the *Width*, *Segments* and *Shape* values in the *Operator Box*, lower down the *Shape* below 0.5:

[image]

Comment: To most folks, that pointy thing looks like a _corner_. To moonboots, it looks like a _side_ , that hasn't yet reached its potential. :)

Comment: yes at first I had the reflex to flatten the corners but I remembered another shape that was quite similar and that I've done with bevel  ^^

Answer (score 0):

If it lines up with the local orientation you can scale the points flat since its not lined up for global. If not you can make a custom axis on that 45° angle and scale to flat one at a time. Not sure how else since its on an angle.